# Insert node into binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have been plugging away at a Binary Search Tree implementation for a few days now and I am to the point where I know that my root is being populated through the use of my 'insert()' (I can see this when I debug, using Eclipse). Why won't my other nodes get added to the tree?

Here is my BST Class:

```
package binarySearchTree;

public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {

@SuppressWarnings("hiding")
private class BinarySearchTreeNode<T>{
    public BinarySearchTreeNode left, right;
    private T data; //LINE 8

    private BinarySearchTreeNode (T data,BinarySearchTreeNode left, BinarySearchTreeNode right ) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
private BinarySearchTreeNode<T> root;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private T search(T target, BinarySearchTreeNode<T> ptr) {
    //find target in subtree A ptr
    if (root == null || ptr == null) {
        return root; //target is not in tree
    }
    int compare = target.compareTo(ptr.data); //compareTo(ptr.data);
    if (compare == 0) {
        return ptr.data; //target is found
    }
    if (compare < 0) {
        return search(target, ptr.left);
    }
    if (compare > 0) {
        return search(target, ptr.right);
    }
    return target;
}
public T search(T target) {
    return search(target);
}
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return root == null;
} 
/* To insert a data into a BST, 1st search for the data, 
 * if the data is found = duplicate data error
 * if the data is NOT found = a null pointer
 * Make this null pointer point to a NewNode holding data
 * new values go into the BST as leaves
 * Using public boolean insert (T node) & 
 * private boolean insert (T Node, BSTNode<T> ptr) as a recursive method
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private boolean insert(T value, BinarySearchTreeNode<T> ptr) {
    //T data = null;
    //insert data in a child of ptr, return false if duplicate is found
    //Precondition: ptr must not be null
    int compare = value.compareTo(ptr.data); //LINE 55
    if (compare == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if (compare < 0) {
        if (ptr.left == null) {
            //found insertion point
            BinarySearchTreeNode<T> node = new BinarySearchTreeNode<>(value, null, null);
            ptr.left.data = node; //insert data in new node
            return true;
        } 
    } else {
        return insert(value, ptr.left); //LINE 67
    }
    if (compare > 0) {
        if (ptr.right == null) {
            BinarySearchTreeNode<T> node = new BinarySearchTreeNode<>(value, null, null);
            ptr.right.data = node;
            return true;
        } else {
            return insert(value, ptr.right);                    
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public boolean insert(T value) {     
    if (isEmpty()) {              
        root = new BinarySearchTreeNode<T>(value, null, null);  
        return true;  
    }
    return insert(value, root); // LINE 85  
} 
}
```

And here is my Main(), eventually I would like to print the values of my BST in the console but first I know they need to be added to the tree:

```
package binarySearchTree;
```

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    BinarySearchTree<String> bstStrings = new BinarySearchTree<String>();

    String s = "Hello";
    String s1 = "World";
    //String s2 = "This Morning";

    bstStrings.insert(s);
    bstStrings.insert(s1); //LINE 15
    //bstStrings.insert(s2);

    while (true){
        if (!bstStrings.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println(bstStrings + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("You should have values above this line!");break;
    }   
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `root` should be of `BinarySearchTree<T>` and not `T`
As a result you are not storing the values in the subtrees of the root.
Replace this:
`return insert((T) value, node);`
with
`return insert((T) value, root);`

in your code replace as follows:

```
public boolean insert(T value) {     
    if (isEmpty()) {              
        root = new BinarySearchTreeNode((T) value, null, null);  
        return true;  
    }
    return insert((T) value, root); // start recursion  
}
```

Otherwise you don't have a tree and the nodes are not linked to each other

**UPDATE:**
You get the NPE because you pass in `insert` the left child of root in the first comparison which is `null`.
You should not return `boolean` but `BinarySearchTreeNode`.
Your method should be:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private BinarySearchTreeNode<T> insert(T value, BinarySearchTreeNode<T> ptr) {  
   if(ptr == null){  
        ptr = new BinarySearchTreeNode<T>(value,null,null);  
        return ptr;  
    }  
    //your code next but return the `ptr`  
}
```

Then in insert you should do:

```
public void insert(T value) {     

    root = insert(value, root); 
}
```

Comment: when I do this, I get the following error under 'insert': The method insert(T, BinarySearchTree<T>.BinarySearchTreeNode) in the type BinarySearchTree<T> is not applicable for the arguments (T, T) ?

Comment: Got it! Thanks; is there anyway to not always need the (T) before everything?

Comment: Why do you cast?Also why isn't it `private class BinarySearchTreeNode<T>`?

Comment: I honestly don't remember now why I took the <T> away. I was casting because I kept receiving Type mismatch errors. I went in just now and changed everything to BinarySearchTreeNode<T> and it seems to be working fine...well actually now I'm gettin a null pointer when I try to enter s1 @ this.data = data;

Comment: You mean here `bstStrings.insert(s1);` you get `NPE`?

Comment: Thread [main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException)) 
 BinarySearchTree$BinarySearchTreeNode<T>.access$0(BinarySearchTree$BinarySearchTreeNode) line: 8 
 BinarySearchTree<T>.insert(T, BinarySearchTree<BinarySearchTreeNode<>>) line: 55 
 BinarySearchTree<T>.insert(T, BinarySearchTree<BinarySearchTreeNode<>>) line: 67 
 BinarySearchTree<T>.insert(T) line: 85 
 Main.main(String[]) line: 15

Comment: Can you add the line numbers in your OP?I don't know what is line 55 or 67.Also how can this happen on `this.data=data`?This is not `null`

Comment: I added the line numbers for where the errors where at, I guess Eclipse doesn't let me copy/past them.  From what I can see in the debugger at line 55, ptr = null, and there is nothing showing when I clicke the line 8 row of the stack trace...all other lines don't show a null value anywhere?

Comment: Didn't you change the `insert` like in my answer?You still have the old code in the OP.Show the code you are debugging'

Comment: I did it exactly how you suggested at first, then I stopped casting (T). The result was the same both ways though...I updated the code in the OP!

Comment: I think it is because you pass `null` in the `value.compareTo`.But how do you get this method?You just declare `T` and not `T extends Comparable`.Post you complete code

Comment: it didn't indent when I copy/pasted, I moved the whole statement into scope; T extends Comparable<T> is there now.  When I look at value.CompareTo in the debugger, it says that value = "World" and ptr = null; I think that it is trying to compare "World" to null...This method is how the professor told us to do it.

Comment: Thank you for all the time you spent helping me with this! I have made your suggested comments from above and it seems to be working well! :)

Answer (score 0):

After the first insertion, you create new nodes, but don't do anything with them.